# Refused to execute script from 'chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable,and strict MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: reactjs, django, nginx

i have a django rest framework + reactjs app in frontend ,
It has deployed successfully in aws, and it's working fine in debug mode,
When i change to production: i get these errors:

Refused to execute script from '***ff1c1f05.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Refused to apply style from 'https://www.dentistconsultationhub.ai/static/css/main.85597d13.chunk.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

can anyone explain to me what mayb be the problem ?
cordially

Comment: This error is the other words for "404" not found. Seek why this file was not found.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this error? I have the same problem